# cambiar elementos del layout en tiempo de ejecucion en adroid studio

Tags: android, android-studio

queria cambiar en tiempo de ejecucion los elementos del layout de una activiy. Para ser mas concreto lo que quiero es que, dependiendo de lo que se seleccione en un spinner (diario,semanal,mensual) aparezcan unos elementos u otros, en funcion de lo que se seleccione, es decir: si selecciono diario apareceran tres textview (desayuno,comida,cena) y si selecciono semanal aparecera solo un textview donde hay que insertar el dia. Este es el codigo de la activity:

```
public class Anadir extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner frecuencia;
    String[] frecuencias= {"Diaria","Semanal","Mensual"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anadir);
        frecuencia=findViewById(R.id.frecuencia);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,frecuencias);
        frecuencia.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

y este el codigo del layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/frecuencia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hola ¿en donde se encuentra el layout que contiene el  textview donde hay que insertar el dia? ¿Cual es el código del listener al cambiar el elemento en el spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es insertar otro Linear Layout dentro de ese layout que tienes para que en tiempo
de ejecución agregues o remuevas los view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/frecuencia"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

En java declaras ese LinearLayout y agregas el Listener del spinner, dependiendo el item seleccionado
se agregan el ó los TextView, aunque mencionas que hay que insertar un texto, supongo que te refieres
a un EditText:

```
   final LinearLayout lay = findViewById(R.id.layout_text);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   frecuencia.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // los TextView y el EditText:
            TextView textView1 = new TextView(Anadir.this);
            TextView textView2 = new TextView(Anadir.this);
            TextView textView3 = new TextView(Anadir.this);
            TextView textView4 = new TextView(Anadir.this);
            EditText editDia = new EditText(Anadir.this);

           // se requiere de LayoutParams para agregar algún view:
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );


            if (position == 0) {
               // remover los view por si seleccionaste otro item del spinner
                lay.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                /*textView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                editDia.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/

                textView1.setText("Desayuno");
                textView2.setText("Comida");
                textView3.setText("Cena");

                textView1.setLayoutParams(params);
                textView2.setLayoutParams(params);
                textView3.setLayoutParams(params);

                // agrega los nuevos view:
                lay.addView(textView1);
                lay.addView(textView2);
                lay.addView(textView3);

            }  if (position == 1) {
                lay.removeAllViewsInLayout();

                editDia.setHint(" escribe el día");
                editDia.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                editDia.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                editDia.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                editDia.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);

                editDia.setLayoutParams(params);
                lay.addView(editDia);

            } if (position == 2) {
                lay.removeAllViewsInLayout();

                textView4.setText("Mensual");
                textView4.setLayoutParams(params);
                lay.addView(textView4);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // set editbox invivible
        }
    });
```